# Laravel migrations work fine, but when I open a page I get "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (13)" - using vagrant

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5.4

I have set up multiple vagrant boxes, where I separated the database in an independent box and the app into its own box. 
Worth noting that I am not using laravel homestead. Both servers running CentOS 7.

I can connect from HeidiSQL on my windows machine, I can even run `php artisan migrate --seed` via ssh and it migrates the tables perfectly fine. However when I open pages that are dependent on database connections, I get `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.3.16' (13)`.

It is also worth mentioning that I am having file permission problems and laravel is not able to cache the views as I am getting the following: `file_put_contents(/var/www/html/autofollow/storage/framework/sessions/N3Z5v2PxiKdgbCwOxXZylmnLZYbgCE4UEOM7uluq): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

As weird as it sounds, it might have to do something with permissions. I tried everything regarding file permissions, setting the owner and group to apache with `chown -R vagrant:apache`, and even changing all permissions to 777 for testing purposes, but nothing works.

At this point I am having a big headache, and really hope someone with the same experience will be able to help me out.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: This is an example where it gets triggered

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
 */
public function index()
{

    $plans = Plan::all();

    return view("frontend.pricing", compact("plans"));
}
```

Comment: Post the code that results in the error

Comment: It is the usual laravel code. I believe the problem to be on a server level, since the code is pretty much standard and works great outside VM.

Comment: how do we debug this without code? The "usual" laravel code

Comment: I edited the post, the code is basically a model call which uses the usual config file from laravel database connection configuration. How I know that the configuration is fine? Because migrations already work, and they use the same env file. That's what makes it a weird problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed both problems by disabling SELinux:

```
sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

and change it to disabled:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

To check the status:

```
sestatus
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running this at the app root

```
sudo chgrp -R vagrant storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Your permission problem doesn't allow Laravel to create the session file

Comment: I have tried changing owner, groups and permission at the VM level, nothing really worked which makes it one of the weirdest problems I had. Just tried your again, and nothing really. :(